# Time Complexity- while loop divided by 2

Tags: performance

what will be the exact step count(growth function) and time complexity of the following algorithm?

```
1.set i=0
2.Repeat steps 3-6 till i<=n
3.    set j=n
4.    while j>0
5.        j=j/2
6.    i=i+1
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, is there something specific you need help understanding with? Because "do my homework for me" is not something many people want to do, but many like answering "I have issues understanding X. I think Y. What am I missing?".

Comment: i am not getting the growth function of while loop?

Comment: Try to think about it in terms of `n` and think through the code like the computer would. Maybe think it through with an example like `n=4` - how many iterations would it do? Then, try to find out how to say that more generally for any `n`

Comment: A compile/programming language that is worth using will delete lines 3, 4 and 5 (reducing it to `i=0; while(i <=n) i++;`) and then probably optimize it into `i=0; if(i <=n) i = n+1;`. Therefore the time complexity should be `O(1)` for all values of `n`.

Comment: @Brendan You are right, for the optimized code, but I doubt their school actually expects that answer.